# Sql + ElasticSearch or NoSQL? Also, can I do this with existing PHP code

Tags: php, sql, elasticsearch, rdbms, nosql

I know that there is an abundance of articles and questions to related topic and I Have been researching them from a few days now and I am more confused then ever.

I am newbie to website world and I learned and almost fully developed a website using MySQL, PHP and JavaScript. I was adding search feature using elastic search and I got confused if I should stick with MySQL and use it in conjunction with ElasticSearch or should I change to any NoSQL db?

Presently I have interconnected tables like users (this table has lots of optional fields) and customers(which has a column for different role of customer), articles, likes, rating, comments and appointment tables.

The data in these tables might need to change later, and I do require filtering and personalisation. I would be using an external payment gateway. 
I have no experience in noSql or newSql. I fear that if I change to noSql the data might be a mess. Also, I would like to realise it quickly. That being said, it would be easier to switch now then later as I don't have any data stored.

Should I change the type of database? If yes to which and can I do that by just changing my sql queries in php to no SQL (how to do that)? How much of the coding will I have to change and how to do it efficiently? Or could/should I add data for personalisation to ElasticSearch?

Thanks for your help and please bear with me if this seems like an obvious choice!

Comment: You could use both MySQL and elasticsearch. You can use MySQL to store all the data which needs to be ATOMIC in nature. And you can use elasticsearch to store the articles and comment in separate indices. Even if you change the article you can re-index the article. ElasticSearch will give you flexibility in searching over articles.

Comment: So users in sql with optional fields? Also, does this mean that I should change my php for articles. I also want users to be able to search for other users/customer (that is more important) and filter the search accordingly??

Comment: Your users will have fixed number of columns in which some fields might be null ? You can search other users using MySQL also. Also , If not much of an problem you can have user in elasticSearch only. So you will have 3 indices one for user, one for articles and one for comments. But you need to denormalise the data properly to be able to store everything in elastic

Comment: My problem is that I don't know ElasticSearch/noSql.. and all my code is written using php pdo statements.. also if I choose noSql should I choose ElasticSearch or something else like mongodb or Cassandra. I have one search which can search other users/article using sql locally but I thought I would a global search in navigation bar where user can search anything. Could you please advice me on way how to make a shift from my current setup to a NoSQL 1.. also currently my localhost was on windows should I move to Ubuntu?

Comment: And yes users have column with fields which can be null (certain type of users) I have 2 tables 1 for user and 1 for customer (this doesn't have that many null fields)

Comment: If you need to support search on article and questions. ElasticSearch can simplify your task a lot. Cassandra is for heavy writes and column oriented data store, but it won't help your cause. I haven't used mongodb So, cann't comment about it. You can try learning elasticsearch.  Regarding your system it depends on the performance and your ease of use.

Comment: Can queries be done with php + ElasticSearch?

Comment: Yes. have a look at this link ( https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/_quickstart.html )

Comment: I will look into this thanks

Comment: Hi again... What if I need to do &quot;union&quot; between &quot;tables&quot;... As I said I have user and customer tables but in many cases I have to run a query (for example to see if email exists) against both.. as I read upon noSql it says joins are not great/or there with noSql... In this case what would be the best option?? Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Hey, in noSQL you should try to denormalize data as much as possible. And get the result in single query. If not possible , you can query first the user to get email of user and then run second query on customer to find if there is any customer with this email. NoSQL are not good with joins , so try and denormalize your data as much as possible.

Comment: But in this case how to denormalize the data.. I mean I get that for example in an article I might have to copy username, name and id field (same for comments/rating?) But when I have to insert or check against something so that only one of that item (username or email) exists how to do that? Run separate queries and then put an or in between?